# React, different templates based on prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Lets say I got a rest response of following:

```
"xxx.function.classes": [
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.Alarm",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.BooleanControl",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.BooleanSensor",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.ColorControl",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.Keypad",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.MediaControl",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.Meter",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.MultiLevelControl",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.MultiLevelSensor",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.VolumeControl",
"com.xxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.WakeUp"
]
```

And I want to render out different markup for the different classes in my component..

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {triggerFBEvent, triggerFBClearEvent} from '../actions/functionblocksActions'


// @connect((store) => {
//   return {
//     fbs: store.functionblocks.functionblocks
//   }
// })
export default class Functionblock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {

    };
    this._getType = this._getType.bind(this)

  }


  render() {
    let functionType = <FunctionType />;

      return( 



      <div className="switch clearfix">
        {functionType}
        <span>{this.props.fbName}</span>
        <input id={this.props.fbID} className="toggle toggle-round" type="checkbox" checked={this.props.power} />
        <label htmlFor={this.props.fbID} data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></label>
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

How would I accomplish this? Is a switch the way to go? Or different classes in the component for all different variations? I want different markup based on the response I get in the prop.

Could someone help me with an example? Much appreciated.

Comment: Considering that you will also have to map the package plus class name to a specific import, mapping using a switch statement would probably be the safest bet.

Comment: maybe something like `import * as FunctionClasses from './FunctionClasses` and `<FunctionClasses[type] />`

Comment: can you make a small example what you are trying to do, the code looks ugly and it's not clear what it should show us..

Comment: @Timo Could you help me with an example of a switch that can return markup containing props to the render funciton?